# identifying similar cell content from one worksheet in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel workbooks. A column in one workbook contains names which i need to match to corresponding name in a column within a second workbook.

How do i do this automatically for the all records without doing individual searches?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have more information? Seems like Index/Match would do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information in the question. But as per following assumptions, below code will give you result as shown in the image.

**Assumptions:**

**1.** As mentioned in the question ***match corresponding name***, I am assuming that you want to match data row wise i.e. match row1-row1, row2-row2, and so on.
**2.** Two files to compare are `file1` and `file2` having data in `Sheet3` and `Sheet2` respectively. (Change file name and sheet name as required)
**3.** End result is highlighting matching names in *Green* and non-matching names in *Red* color. (as nothing has been specified in question regarding the desired output I am also displaying "Match" and "No Match" in `file2` as another option)

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, matchCount As Long

    'two sheets to be used of different files
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("file1").Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("file2").Sheets("Sheet2")

    matchCount = 0

    'get last row with data from file1        
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'loop through all the names in column A
    'starting with 2 to exclude header
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If ws1.Range("A" & i) = ws2.Range("A" & i) Then
            'if names match change cell color to green in file2
            'also write match in column B
            ws2.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = "Match"
            matchCount = matchCount + 1
        Else
            'if names does not match change cell color to red in file2
            'also write no match in column B
            ws2.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ws2.Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = "No Match"
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Out of " & lastRow - 1 & " there were " & matchCount & " cells matching."
End Sub
```

**NOTE :** Both files should be open in the same instance of the Excel for this code to work.

[image]